# How to save app data on Google Drive?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I want to use **Google Drive** **as** **server** to store app data. So, I have written all the data to a file and then upload that file to Drive.

**Code:**

```
try {
//         outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
           outputStream.write(text.getBytes());
        } 
   catch (IOException e1) {
           Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
   }


  MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
              .setMimeType("text/txt").setTitle("testfile.txt").build();

  IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                        .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                        .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                      .setInitialDriveContents(result.getDriveContents())
                        .build(mGoogleApiClient);
  try {
        startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
  } 
  catch (SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Failed to launch file chooser.");
   }
```

Is it possible that whenever the device is connected to internet, the app data will get synchronized with data available on Google Drive? 
I read about **Google Drive API**, but was unable to understand:

1) how will the synchronization happen?
2) can we synchronize with the file stored in **App folder** of Google Drive?
3) do I need to write the file to Google Drive or I'll have to save the file to some container and Google will update itself when connected to internet(as in ios)?

Please guide me.

**EDIT**

Before creating a file in drive, I have done a check.

```
Query query = new Query.Builder()
        .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain"))
        .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "appdata.txt")).build();

Drive.DriveApi.query(getGoogleApiClient(), query).setResultCallback(
                metadataCallback);


final private ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult> metadataCallback = new ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {

@Override
public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {  
metadata = result.getMetadataBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < metadata.getCount(); i++) {

    DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(),
                            metadata.get(i).getDriveId());
    file.trash(getGoogleApiClient());
 }
```

Is it a wrong way to proceed?

Comment: Ask yourself when is it important that you synch the app with drive? Is it on Pause, OnCreate, on the Main Page? That is when you connect with drive.

Comment: I am unable to sync the file that are stored in **App folder**.

Comment: @SmulianJulian I am able to save file to Drive, but every time it creates a new file with same metadata.How to sync the old file with the new one ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173542/hot-to-replace-file-in-google-drive

Answer (score 3):

newCreateFileActivityBuilder() will start an activity to let the user choose a location in their Drive to create the file.
If you want to use the App folder you'll need to follow the instructions in https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder

Comment: I have followed the instructions given on above site. I am able to save my file but every time it creates a new file instead of replacing a old file. Is it possible to replace/edit old file in app/root folder?